# Intel OpenCL only detecting the nvidia platform

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, opencl

I just installed the intel opencl sdk on ubuntu 15.10.  I am trying to use it and for some reason I am only able to detect the nvidia opencl platform.

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    cl_uint nids;
    clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &nids);
    printf("Platforms = %d\n", nids);
    cl_platform_id* plat_ids = malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * nids);
    clGetPlatformIDs(nids, plat_ids, NULL);


    for(int i = 0; i < nids; i++)
    {
        char name[1000];
        clGetPlatformInfo(plat_ids[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, 1000, name, NULL);
        puts(name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs...

```
Platforms = 1
NVIDIA Corporation
```

This seems strange to me because I am not even linking with the nvidia libOpenCL.so.  Here is my compile command from eclipse

```
make all 
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-6.0.0.1049/opencl-1.2-sdk-6.0.0.1049/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
Finished building: ../main.c

Building target: OpenCLTest
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-6.0.0.1049/opencl-1.2-6.0.0.1049/lib64 -o "OpenCLTest"  ./main.o   -lOpenCL
Finished building target: OpenCLTest
```

As you can see I only link with the Intel library.

Comment: Any chance you have an ICD driver installed?

Comment: I do i am just starting to figure that out.

Comment: Right, so ICD will allow multiple drivers to pretend to be the "one" driver. This is about AMD, but I believe it applies to "any" ICD compatible driver (except for "where you go to get your driver" of course)

Comment: Is your CPU in the list of devices supported by Intel OpenCL implementation? OpenCL ICD (named opencl.dll on Windows, no experience with Linux but libOpenCL.so is probably the one) is not vendor-specific; it simply lists all OpenCL devices which are registered by their drivers. On Windows this information is read from registry; Linux should have something similar.